# Error when login to mysql from java code

Tags: java

I want to login from mySql database.Everything is ok but when i login come my error message 2 times(Username or Password does not match.). I think my Loop is problem. Please help me. My method is below.....

```
private void loginProcess() {
        String username = jTextFieldLoginUsername.getText().toUpperCase();
        String password = jPasswordFieldLoginPassword.getText();

        List<LoginModel> list = new ArrayList<LoginModel>();
        LoginDao loginDao = new LoginDao();
        list = loginDao.doLogin();
        if (list.size() != 0) {
            for (LoginModel model : list) {
                String uName = model.getUsername();
                String pWord = model.getPassword();
                String userType = model.getUserType();
//                System.out.println("uName::" + uName);

                if (username.equals(uName) && password.equals(pWord)) {
                    if (userType.equals("1")) {
                        dispose();
                        Admin admin = new Admin();
                        admin.setVisible(true);
                    } else if (userType.equals("2")) {
                        dispose();
                        Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
                        purchase.setVisible(true);
                    } else if (userType.equals("3")) {
                        dispose();
                        Sales sales = new Sales();
                        sales.setVisible(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Username or Password does not match.");
                    jTextFieldLoginUsername.requestFocus();
                    jTextFieldLoginUsername.selectAll();
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're member for two months.. Time to learn how to post a clear code. Please edit your post.

Comment: Please share exception message

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Username or Password does not match.");

Comment: Please post your error message by editing your question.

Comment: what us uName and pWord? Why are you using toUpperCase() for the username? Maybe you have a newline or space character somewhere, try using trim().

Comment: Good lord are you loading and examining every login combination?  How many of those could you have?  Also, you throw the alert every time a given LoginModel doesn't match.  If you get 50 loginmodels in your db you'll show 49 even if user gets right username/pword.  Try doing the match as part of the query.  Also, hash and salt your passwords.  Also don't use md5.

Comment: @Mezbaz For every nonmatching user returned by `doLogin` a optionpane will pop up. You should check what is returned by this method.

Comment: @Taylor== Thanks. you got my problem exactly . Please correction my code. I am trying this for 3 hours.

Comment: It's more than correcting the code, your fundamental approach is wrong.  Your best bet is to look at how Spring Seucirty does authentication and go from there.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you go through a list of possible logins, every time the credentials you got do not match, you print the message. So if you have three items in that list, two of them will cause the message to be printed. Even if you already found a matching user before.

I would recommend somewhat changing the logic around your for-loop:

```
boolean success = false
for (LoginModel model : list) {
            ...
            if (username.equals(uName) && password.equals(pWord)) {
                      success = true;
                      ...
            } // no else here
 }
 if(!success) {
      // do the error-message stuff 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String username = jTextFieldLoginUsername.getText().toUpperCase();
```

and

```
String uName = model.getUsername();
```

should be the same? Try adding .toUpperCase() to uName. Does that help?